# Upload Image from angularjs using Springboot to FTP

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, multipartform-data

I am trying to pick a file and upload it to FTP.
For now I get the a 415 (media type unsupported) error when consuming springboot service in angularjs when sending the image.

This is my angular controller:

```
Controllers.controller('UploadCtrl', [ '$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.doUploadFile = function() {
            var file = $scope.uploadedFile;
            var url = "/ui/upload";

            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('uploadfile', file);

            var config = {
                transformRequest : angular.identity,
                transformResponse : angular.identity,
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type' : undefined
                }
            }

            $http.post(url, data, config).then(function(response) {
                $scope.uploadResult = response.data;
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.uploadResult = response.data;
            });
        };
    } ]);
```

My Service Controller JAVA:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public String upload(@RequestParam("uploadfile") MultipartFile file) throws Exception {
    try {
        return "You successfully uploaded - " + file.getOriginalFilename();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("FAIL! Maybe You had uploaded the file before or the file's size > 500KB");
    }
}
```

For now just getting the file name. What am 'I doing wrong when consuming the POST ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

### HTML

```
<img ng-src="{{profilePicturePath}}" class="img-responsive"
     alt="Image Not found" style="height:150px; width: 150px;">
<input type="file" class="form-control" style="display: none;"
       file-model="profileFile" multiple name="profileFile"
       id="profileFile" accept="image/*"/>
```

### JS

```
$scope.profileFile = null;
$scope.$watch('profileFile', function (profileFile) {
    if (profileFile && profileFile.name) {
        if (profileFile.size / 1012 < 512) {
            if (profileFile.type.startsWith("image/")) {
                uploadProfilePicture(profileFile);
            }
        } 
    }
});

function uploadProfilePicture(profileFile) {
    aspirantService.uploadProfilePicture(profileFile).then(function (response) {
        getProfilePicturePath();
    });
}
```

---

```
this.uploadProfilePicture = function (file) {
            var fd = new FormData();
            fd.append("doc", file);
            return $http.post(Server.url + 'aspirant/pic/', fd, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
            });
        };
```

### and JAVA

```
 @Path("pic")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.WILDCARD)
    public Response uploadProfilePicture(MultipartFormDataInput input, @Context UserSession session) {


        for (Map.Entry<String, List<InputPart>> entry : input.getFormDataMap().entrySet()) {
            List<InputPart> list = entry.getValue();
            for (Iterator<InputPart> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
                InputPart inputPart = it.next();
                try {
                    MultivaluedMap<String, String> header = inputPart.getHeaders();
                    String fileName = RequestHeaderInfo.getFileName(header);
                    String contentType = RequestHeaderInfo.getContentType(header);
                    InputStream inputStream = inputPart.getBody(InputStream.class, null);


                        return Response.status(Response.Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
                    }

                //here code for write file



                    return Response.ok(proxy).build();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error while getting document!", ex);
                }
            }
        }
        return Response.ok().build();
    }
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks. I'll give it a try.

What do you reckon is wrong with what i have ?

Comment: i haven't try your code...but this will help ful to you...its working for my case

Comment: Can you share the libraries you used? is it resteasy or jersey ? or is jax-rs?